# PHP ACPu storage as session holder

Tags: php, performance, security

I am thinking about improving performance by elimineting files access.
As far as I know std PHP session works over file system.
Even on SSD disks reading / saving data has larger impact on time than using memory storage like ACPu.
I would like to store session as cache entry with some secure name and send cookie with that name to client.
I know about security risk - however it is similiar to std session (session hijacking).

Do you see some disadventages of that idea?

Comment: I personally think that those few bytes written to the filesystem have way less impact compared to working on the latency, code quality and database queries. I would consider looking for improvement there.

Comment: It may happen that there is no db connection in my app. And regardless performance issues - I'm just interested about that solution.